# Neo4j - get all articulation vertices

Tags: neo4j

using Neo4j, I would like to **get all the articulation vertices** (vertices/nodes that when removed, splits the graph in more connected components) from my graph.

**Is there an easy way to do it (without completely re-implementing DFS)?**

Alternatively, **is there a possibility to do a traversal with the exclusion of a certain node? (and its relationships)** (I have a fairly small number of nodes, using neo4j embedded so optimal O() is not critical)

Answer (score 0):

you could exclude nodes by not continuing past them, e.g. with the Traversal Framework, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded-traversal.html#_new_traversal_framework. Also, you could implement your own RelationshipExpander that will not expand relationships to your node to avoid in a traversal, see http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.5.M01/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/RelationshipExpander.html

HTH

/peter